# Problem installing Packet Fence

Tags: 13.04, update-manager

I am Installing packet Fence on Ubuntu 13.04 by following [this](http://www.unixmen.com/install-packetfence-network-access-control-on-ubuntu/) tutorial and I'm getting error as some packages are broken .
This is what I have added in my packetfence.list file as given on the tutorial

```
deb http://inverse.ca/downloads/PacketFence/ubuntu precise precise
```

I think problem is with precise since it is an 12.04 and I'm using ubuntu 13.04 and I don't know what I'm supposed to add in place of precise .If I add raring in place of precise it gives me an warnning saying  /media/ankita/OSFYJune13/boot/other_isos/ubuntu-13.04-server-amd64.iso wat shuld i add in my packetfence.list?

Answer (score 0):

Use deb http://inverse.ca/downloads/PacketFence/ubuntu precise precise in your packetfence.list.
That will install the right dependencies anyway.

If you need more help, use the PacketFence community mailing list.
https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/packetfence-users

We will be happy to help you.

Regards,
Loick
Network-Security Architect at Inverse
for PacketFence NAC.

Comment: i tried same thing first I'm getting as some broken pakage errors

Comment: precise is the  ubuntu version name rt?

Comment: what does precise specify ubuntu version rt?